# Add new columns to exsiting table in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL that creates the table below:

```
SELECT c.cOLUMN1 , c.cOLUMN2 , COALESCE (sc.cOLUMN3, 'XXX') AS cOLUMN3
FROM tabel AS c 


COLUMN1  COLUMN2   COLUMN3 

   1        1        XXX     
   1        1        26785  
   1        1        23432   
   1        1        XXX
```

I want to add two new columns - if the value in column3 is equal too 'XXX' then the new in 
**NEWCOLUMN_A** should be '0' and **NEWCOLUM_B** should be '1'.

Otherwise the new in **NEWCOLUMN_A** should be '1' and **NEWCOLUM_B** should be '1'.

As shown below:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2   COLUMN3  NEWCOLUMN_A  NEWCOLUMN_B
   1        1        XXX       0            1  
   1        1        26785     1            1           
   1        1        23432     1            1 
   1        1        XXX       0            1
```

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069611/how-can-i-dynamically-create-columns-in-sql-select-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    c.cOLUMN1 , 
    c.cOLUMN2 , 
    COALESCE (c.cOLUMN3, 'XXX') AS cOLUMN3,
    (CASE WHEN COALESCE(c.cOLUMN3, 'XXX') = 'XXX' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NEWCOLUMN_A,
    1 AS NEWCOLUMN_B
FROM tabel AS c
```

Alternatively, since column 3 is derived...

```
SELECT 
    c.cOLUMN1 , 
    c.cOLUMN2 , 
    COALESCE (c.cOLUMN3, 'XXX') AS cOLUMN3,
    (CASE WHEN c.cOLUMN3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NEWCOLUMN_A,
    1 AS NEWCOLUMN_B
FROM tabel AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the columns to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tabel
    ADD NEWCOLUMN_A BIT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabel
    ADD NEWCOLUMN_B BIT NULL;
```

then `UPDATE` the table:

```
UPDATE tabel
SET NEWCOLUMN_A = CASE WHEN COLUMN3 = 'XXX' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    NEWCOLUMN_B = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking to accomplish.

```
Declare @string As nvarchar(50)
Set @string = 'xxx'
Select CASE WHEN @string  = 'xxx' Then 0 Else 1 End as NEWCOLUM_A, 1 as NEWCOLUM_B
set @string = 'yyy'
Select CASE WHEN @string  = 'xxx' Then 0 Else 1 End as NEWCOLUM_A, 1 as NEWCOLUM_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cOLUMN1 
     , c.cOLUMN2 
     , COALESCE(c.cOLUMN3, 'XXX') AS cOLUMN3
     , CASE WHEN c.cOLUMN3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEWCOLUMN_A 
     , 1 AS NEWCOLUM_B 
FROM tabel AS c
```